# SSH and SSHFS not completely connecting

Tags: ssh, sshfs

I'm trying to connect between an Ubuntu and CentOS and reverse. From both sides I get black screen where I can press enter but nothing happens, not being asked for password.

examples:

SSH root@1.2.3.4
SSHFS root@1.2.3.5:/tmp /tmp/1

Ports are ok, connection being made (not refuses, I get that only on wrong ports), but there's just the black screen and nothing else. Alter a while I get timed out.

What can be the problem ?

Comment: Could you edit your question with the *-vvv* ssh option output?

Comment: Note: same thing I get with mount -t. What do you meam, maxxvw ?

Comment: Do you mean that you are able to ssh into 1.2.3.4 and then "mount -t sshfs root@1.2.3.5:/tmp /tmp/1" failed?

Comment: No, I mean both SSH and SHFS commands (separately) have the same result: connection is not denied, but I get black screen where I can press enter.

Comment: Then try: "ssh -vvv root@1.2.3.4" to see if message can help

Comment: Same result, its saying debug 1 reading configuration, debug2: ssh_connect needpriv 0, debug1: connecting to 1.2.3.4 [1.2.3.4] port 22 and then same black screen (nothing else happens).

Answer (score 0):

I think tcp connection cannot be established, please make sure you didn't forget to set port forwarding on your router or something like that.
If you have another way to connect or a physical access to this server, try to sniff network with tcpdump from 1.2.3.4:

```
tcpdump -i [interface] tcp port 22
```

Also try to connect with netcat for exemple:

```
nc 1.2.3.4 22
```

This should print ssh server version.

Comment: NC returns nothing. Same for TCPdump on ICMP and 22 (although ICMP works). TCPdump does see the broadcasting and other things of running it with no parameters.

Comment: Seems to be something wrong with the virtualinterface IP. I can SSH to the WAN one, I'll do further testing.Thanks for the info.